# How do sum of column with date wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following data in table :

```
qty      dttime
15.83   2015-04-28 18:58:25.000
3.78    2015-04-28 18:58:27.000
29.39   2015-04-28 18:59:41.000
25.6    2015-04-29 19:01:23.000
2.39    2015-04-29 19:04:24.000
8.9     2015-04-30 19:07:25.000
8.18    2015-04-30 19:10:32.000
1.92    2015-04-30 19:13:48.000
```

Now i want to do sum of qty date wise and show output like below :

```
qty      dttime

49      2015-04-28 
27.99   2015-04-29 
19      2015-04-30
```

How can i do sum of all these data and order it by date wise ?

Comment: you tagged 3 different releases of SQL Server. Be sure to only tag the relevant one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the date (since SQL Server 2008) using the `date` data type.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select cast(dttime as date) as dte, sum(qty)
from t
group by cast(dttime as date)
order by dte;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cast()`:

```
select sum(qty) qty,  cast(dttime as date) dttime 
from table t
group by cast(dttime as date);
```